# Rails ignores collection route and routes to show action instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following routes:

```
resources :transactions do
  collection do
    post :detail
  end
end
```

When I got to http://localhost:3000/transactions/detail, rails gives me this error:

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TransactionsController#show**

*Couldn't find Transaction with id=detail*

This makes me think the show route is taking precedence over my collection route, but I can't figure out why. Very similar to this issue: [Rails ignores collection route and goes with show action instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099466/rails-ignores-collection-route-and-goes-with-show-action-instead), but I don't have a duplicate resources :transactions entry.

Comment: @RahulSingh is correct here - if you are hitting your show action then you are sending a GET request - not POST. You can't just type `http://localhos:3000/transactions/detail` into the address bar, use cURL or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) or better yet a [request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rahul is right. When you visit a web address in your browser, you're making a GET request. Try this instead:

```
resources :transactions do
  collection do
    get :detail
  end
end
```

If that's the only route you're nesting, it can be shortened to:

```
resources :transactions do
  get :detail, on: :collection
end
```

Comment: Thanks Brent, I think there must be something wrong with my link_to: <%= link_to 'Detail', detail_transactions_path, method: :post %>, which is resolving as http://localhost:3000/transactions/detail. I think you've pointed me in the right direction though. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd like help with a solution, I'd be happy to chat about it