# Rails - routes resources duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have the following routes set up in my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :bookings do
    collection do
      get :my_bookings
    end
  end

  resources :spaces, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show] do
    resources :bookings, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show]
  end

  resources :bookings do
    resources :payments, only: :new
  end

  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/stripe-webhooks'
end
```

I have repeated `resources :bookings` 3 times: twice because I know that is a good practice to avoid nested resources of more than a level and another for the collection.

When I added the collection part at the end of the routes it was ignored by rails Rails and it was hitting the show action instead.

I read [Rails ignores collection route and goes with show action instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099466/rails-ignores-collection-route-and-goes-with-show-action-instead) and moved the collection part at the end.

Now everything is working, but the routes file is bulky and resources :booking is duplicated 3 times. Is there a way to refactor these routes with less repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really going to improve the routes if you just focus on avoiding repetition. DRY is good but it really should be pretty far down the list of priorities when refactoring. Rather you want to focus on making your routes RESTful, [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) and handling the same resource in different contexts:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  # /bookings/my_bookings is not very RESTful as its "backwards" 
  # a better solution is /my/bookings or /user/bookings which are real nested routes
  # @see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources
  resource :user, only: [] do
    # this will route /user/bookings to Users::BookingsController
    resources :bookings, only: [:index], module: :users
  end

  resources :spaces, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show] do
    # shallow: true will prevent the member routes from being nested 
    # it will also prevent resources :payments from being nested in `/spaces/`
    resources :bookings, shallow: true do
       resources :payments, only: :new, shallow: true
    end
  end

  root to: 'pages#home'
  get :about, to: 'pages#about'

  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/stripe-webhooks'
end
```

There are two ways really to handle the same resource in different contexts. You can mosh everything into the same controller and add a code branch based on the presence of a "parent id" parameter or you can route the requests to different controllers. The later avoids violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: I created a separate controller:                                    
                                                                              ```#controllers/users/bookings_controller.rb```. with the content:                                                                            ```class Users::BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookings = current_user.bookings
  end
end
```     Also the view ``` views/users/bookings/index.html.erb``` .  Everything is working well, not sure if I overcomplicated the folder structures and violated some name conventions...

Comment: Perfect. Its not overcompliced at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the two top-level (non-nested) `resources :bookings` blocks, like this:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :bookings do
    collection do
      get :my_bookings
    end

    resources :payments, only: :new
  end

  resources :spaces, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show] do
    resources :bookings, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show]
  end

  root to: 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/stripe-webhooks'
end
```

That should be equivalent, and a bit neater. You will have to keep the nested `resources :bookings` though, but that's and totally OK. And necessary for the `/spaces/:space_id/bookings` URL structure.